# Extract json data from an array in PySpark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to flatten and extract only one value (time) from the JSON file and its array (records), and store it in the new column (date). Then I want to get the max date from that column.
However, it seems like I can only get the time value from the first batch of the records array, but not all the other records array (as there is more, `newRecord` string gives us the new records array).

Could you perhaps give me any hints how can I adjust my solution that I have to make sure I get all time values from every records array?

Thank you in advance!

My JSON file format:

```
root
 |-- newRecord: string (nullable = true)
 |-- records: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- val1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- time: string(nullable = true)
```

My solution as of now:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.read.json("....json")
df.select (
    "newRecord",
    F.transform('records', lambda x: to_timestamp(x['time'])).alias('date')).agg(max('date')).first()
```

Ïnput:

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
             "val1": 37.99711,
             "val2": 231.7571,
             "time":  "2023-01-17T14:39:09.207Z"
        },
        {
             "val1": 37.99711,
             "val2": 231.7571,
             "time":  "2023-01-16T14:37:09.207Z"
        }
```

Output:

Latest (max) date over all records.

Comment: the schema doesn't look right to me. If you have this schema, you would get ambiguous column error.  Could you do `df.printSchema()` after the read.json and update the schema in your question?

Comment: @Emma Hi Emma, I just updated the schema; I can only see one mention of the records. However, when I preform my solution, and want to get the latest date, I know I am not getting the correct result; I am only getting the latest date of, it seems, few records. So i am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Could you also add your sample data and expected output?  the "max" is not clear yet.  If you want a max in an array per row or max across different rows.  If you give us the expected output, it would be clear.

Comment: @Emma hi Emma, I put some sample there but indeed, I would like to get max across different rows, so from all the records. There are a lot of these records available and I would like to take the latest time out of all of them. Does this help? I am probably doing something wrong with the max function

Comment: does this work? `F.array_max(F.transform('records', lambda x: F.to_timestamp(x['time']))).alias('date'))`.